# Using a list for loop index in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, indexing

I want to generate a loop as follows:

```
j = [0,0,0]
for j[0] in range(10):
    for j[1] in range(10):
        for j[2] in range(10):
```

This will be useful when I calculate something like:

```
vector_sizes = [j[i] * j[i] for i in range(3)]
```

Is there a way to implement this concisely?

For example:

```
for j_vec in range(10), range(10), range(10):
```

Comment: Check out [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: You are looping over the `range`, not over the elements of `j`. If you know this already, your looping variables make you confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

vec_size = 3

for j_vec in product(*([range(2)] * vec_size)):
  print(j_vec)
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```